# Response.Listener Volley in Android (java)

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm beginner in programming, I want to request JSON . I have problem with Response.Listener, It have red underline and the callVolley is red too

This is the script code. Would anyone help me? Thank you

```
 StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                // Cek error node pada json
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Add/update", jObj.toString());

                    callVolley();

                    Toast.makeText(InputActivity.this, jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(InputActivity.this, jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: In Android Studio, `red underline` usually means need to `import` from somewhere.
You can put cursor on it and it will show some hint as also.

Comment: please hover over the red underline and try adding the error is the question too

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting using StringRequest which means response in onResponse(String response) should be a String, instead you are having JSONArray. Please check properly while creating a request.

code should be like this below,

```
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
```